# Constructing angularjs directives with classes

Tags: angularjs, typescript

This is how I currently do it:

```
class AService {
    $http: any;
    $state: any;
    static $inject = ['$http', '$state'];
    constructor($http, $state) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.$state = $state;
    };
```

It becomes alot of boilerplate code to satisfy typescript. Is there any shorter way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify that the parameters should be stored as fields directly in the constructor.

```
class AService {
    static $inject = ['$http', '$state'];
    constructor(private $http, private $state) {
    }
}
```

---

You could also specify the injection parameter array (`$inject`) when you register the type with the angularjs module and remove `$inject` from the class.